# Creating a multi level dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

When I create a multi level dictionary (or JSON) I have to initialize at each level and it overwrites the old data

For example I'd like to create

```
dict1 = {}
for i in ["i","you"]:
    for j in ["have", "has", "had"]:
        for k in ["a","an"]:
            for m in ["apple", "pear"]:
                for n in ["cat","dog"]:
                    dict1[i] = {j:{k:{"fruit":m,"animal":n}}} 
print(dict1)
```

I would like to have the result of

```
{'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'}}},
 'you': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}}}
```

and so on. However I am receiving only the last 2 permutations as they always get overwritten.

Comment: that will result in a key error as i has not yet been initialised. If i initialise dict1[i] = {} that would clear my dictionary everytime i initialise i

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the key every iteration of the inner loops. Use a `list` instead

```
lst = []
for i in ["i", "you"]:
    for j in ["have", "has", "had"]:
        for k in ["a", "an"]:
            for m in ["apple", "pear"]:
                for n in ["cat", "dog"]:
                    lst.append({i: {j: {k: {"fruit": m, "animal": n}}}})

print(lst)
```

Output

```
[{'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'}}}},
 {'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}}}},
 {'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'cat'}}}},
 ...
 {'you': {'had': {'an': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}}}},
 {'you': {'had': {'an': {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'cat'}}}},
 {'you': {'had': {'an': {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'dog'}}}}]
```

Edit

You can keep the `dict` format if you add an additional unique key

```
dict1 = {}
id = 0
for i in ["i", "you"]:
    for j in ["have", "has", "had"]:
        for k in ["a", "an"]:
            for m in ["apple", "pear"]:
                for n in ["cat", "dog"]:
                    dict1[id] = {i: {j: {k: {"fruit": m, "animal": n}}}}
                    id += 1
```

Output

```
{0: {'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'}}}},
 1: {'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}}}},
 2: {'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'cat'}}}},
...
 45: {'you': {'had': {'an': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}}}},
 46: {'you': {'had': {'an': {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'cat'}}}},
 47: {'you': {'had': {'an': {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'dog'}}}}}
```

Edit 2:

Keys in `dict` must be unique, you can't have `i` key more than once. If you don't want to use one of the above options the only other way is to use a `tuple` as the key#

```
dict1 = {}
for i in ["i", "you"]:
    for j in ["have", "has", "had"]:
        for k in ["a", "an"]:
            dict1[(i, j, k)] = {"fruit": "apple", "animal": "dog"}
print(dict1[('i', 'have', 'a')]) # {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}
print(dict1[('i', 'have', 'an')]) # {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}
```

You will still have the issue duplicate keys in the inner loops of `fruit` and `animal` (if you really need them), to get all the options you will still need a list

```
dict1 = {}
for i in ["i", "you"]:
    for j in ["have", "has", "had"]:
        for k in ["a", "an"]:
            dict1[(i, j, k)] = []
            for m in ["apple", "pear"]:
                for n in ["cat", "dog"]:
                    dict1[(i, j, k)].append({"fruit": m, "animal": n})

print(dict1[('i', 'have', 'a')])
print(dict1[('i', 'have', 'an')])

# [{'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'}, {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}, {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'cat'}, {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'dog'}]
# [{'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'}, {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'dog'}, {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'cat'}, {'fruit': 'pear', 'animal': 'dog'}]
```

Comment: thank you for your response. But i would like to use a dictionary instead. the real problem is that i would like to create a lookup table where it should loo something like this price_dict[product_id][parameter_id][time_period] = {"price":price,"effective_date":effective_date}

so that i can look up the price based on the product_id, parameter_id and time_period given. the example given above is to simplyfy the problem abit :)

Comment: @DouglasSim I added another solution.

Comment: Thank you. but the solution to have the lookup factor. Is it possible for 1 of the branches to be {'i': {'have': {'a': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'},'an': {'fruit': 'apple', 'animal': 'cat'}}}
so i can look up the fruit or animal when i have 'i','have' and 'an'

Comment: @DouglasSim You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary, I added another option close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Creating in one shot a nested structure requires a good initialization at each level.
In your approach you can adopt `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
dict1 = tree()

for i in ["i","you"]:
    for j in ["have", "has", "had"]:
        for k in ["a","an"]:
            for m in ["apple", "pear"]:
                for n in ["cat","dog"]:
                    dict1[i][j][k] = {"fruit":m,"animal":n}
```

The output is not exactly a dict, but works in the same way.

Comment: Awesome. I think this will solve it for me. Will reply back in a few hours as i'm trying to create a lookup table based on info taken from an sql table:)